# Android outofmemory while loading image from Assest

Tags: android

I am facing outofmemory while trying to load bitmap image from Assest, Below is my code:

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

InputStream istr = assetManager.open(FILE_NAME);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
```

I am getting below exception most of time I am loading the image:

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(731): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

I have gone throw few articles on managing image size in ImageView. But my code not reaching to that point even.

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the resolution is very big.

You should read the size first, and scale it before load it to the memory.

the best practice for this

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code to your manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```